# How to get my first name and last name in my database to front end?

Tags: javascript, java, html, forms

i can't to get my first name and last name in my database my sql to front end

(first name  = prenom
laste name = nom
because i am French)

my front end formulaire in html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="description"> 
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
    <title>Mangas Supremacy</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="inscription.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="">
            <ul class="logo">
                <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" alt="" width="22%"></a>
            </ul>
            
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <h1>Inscrit toi</h1>
        <form id="inscription-form">
            <label for="nom"> Nom </label>
            <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom"required><br>
            <label for="prenom"> Prenom </label>
            <input type="text" id="prenom" name="prenom"required><br>
            <label for="email"> Email </label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email"required><br>
            <label for="password"> password </label>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password"required><br>
            <button type="submit">S'inscrire</button>
        </form>
    </main>

    <footer></footer>
    <script src="inscription.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

incription.js :

```
const inscriptionForm = document.getElementById('inscription-form');
inscriptionForm.addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const nom = document.getElementById("nom").value;
    const prenom = document.getElementById("prenom").value;
    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value;

    const data = {nom, prenom, email, password}

    fetch('http://localhost:8088/AUTH-SERVICE/api/auth/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
    })
    .then(response => {
        if(response.ok){
            alert('Inscription effectuÃ©e avec succes');
            inscriptionForm.reset();
            window.location.href = "login.html";
        }else{
            alert('Erreur au moment de l inscription');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log('error on register : ', error);

    })
})
```

my backend is in java with my database in sql

(the register and login work i want just to get last name and first name in my database)

Comment: Are there any javascript errors? What's being returned from your fetch? Where exactly is the process going wrong?

Comment: You have not asked a question.

Comment: @jessman5, OP mentioned that their backend *is* in Java.